# MYSQL database connection in my Mac isn't succeeding

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp, mysql-error-1045

I’m using a Mac Book Pro with big sur os. I’m using MySQL as my database service and XAMPP as my local host.
Below is how I tried to establish the database connection using php.

```
<?php 
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "mydb";
$port = "3306";
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database, $port);
if($conn){
  echo "Connected Suuccessfuly";
  return var_dump($conn);
}else{
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

However it comes up with an error as shown below.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MYQO.png)

Any solutions? A help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you got such user with that password which has access to mydb?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual information, post it as text in your question.